# setSelectionRange with on click in chrome does not select on second click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a function that selects the first 5 characters of a input onclick. This works for the very first click. When the input box still has focus, in chrome, a second click within the first 5 characters removes the selection and the caret is blinking at the position of the click.

I expect the first 5 characters to still-be/remain selected.

This appears to be a chrome issue as it works fine in Firefox.

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/valamas/3eaYq/2/

How can I get this working with chrome?

I have tried resetting the selection using

```
sender.setSelectionRange(0, 1);
sender.setSelectionRange(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed [an issue with Chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=32865) (and a two year old issue at that).  To make Chrome behave the same as Firefox, simply wrap the contents of `doSelect` in a `setTimeout` call:

```
function doSelect(sender, e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        sender.setSelectionRange(0, 5);
    }, 0);
}
```

See also: [the updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eaYq/3/)

---

**Update**: The bug is now marked as `FIXED` and will be delivered in Chrome 39.

Comment: Well, ten years later I'm experiencing this kind of issue and this code fixed it!